# Looping a range inside a range

Tags: excel, vba

i a looking to loop a range inside a range.The goal is to take value from a worksheet and paste it to another worksheet. There is in total 120 cell where i need to paste information and i am trying to find a way to not create 120 line... Most cell at the destination is fused so .value is used as it is working. Also i am not good with VBA but i did made something work

currently my code look like this :

```
Sub copy_paste_PST1()

'worksheet
Set remplissage = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Remplissage")
Set pts1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PTS-1")

'tableau entrée PTS-1
Dim tableau_ep As range
Dim nbrligne_ep As Integer
Set tableau_ep = pts1.range("C19:ADV26")
nbrligne_ep = tableau_ep.Rows.Count

'tableau entrée remplissage
Dim tableau_er As range
Dim nbrligne_er As Integer
Set tableau_er = remplissage.range("Q63:AE302")
nbrligne_er = tableau_er.Rows.Count

'tableau sortie PTS 1
Dim tableau_sp As range
Dim nbrligne_sp As Integer
Set tableau_sp = pts1.range("C28:ADS35")
nbrligne_sp = tableau_sp.Rows.Count

'tableau sortie remplissage
Dim tableau_sr As range
Dim nbrligne_sr As Integer
Set tableau_sr = pts1.range("C28:ADS35")
nbrligne_sr = tableau_sr.Rows.Count

'tableau si usage industriel est coché
Dim tableau_t As range
Dim nbrligne_t As Integer
Set tableau_t = pts1.range("F2:ADI2")
nbrligne_t = tableau_t.Columns.Count

'Code start

p_a = 1

r_a = 1

For t = 1 To nbrligne_t Step 27

    If tableau_t(1, t) = "[ X ] Usage industriel général" Then

    'input
    
        'these codes loop as intended but are not grouped, these codes remplace pts1.range("c19:c26").Value = remplissage.range("Q63:Q70").Value
 
        tableau_ep(1, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 1, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 1, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 2, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 2, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 3, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 3, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 4, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 4, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 5, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 5, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 6, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 6, 1).Value
        tableau_ep(1 + 7, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + 7, 1).Value
        
        'these code are grouped but are not looping

        'pts1.range("c19:c26").Value = remplissage.range("Q63:Q70").Value

        pts1.range("D19:D26").Value = remplissage.range("R63:R70").Value

        pts1.range("G19:G26").Value = remplissage.range("S63:S70").Value

        pts1.range("I19:I26").Value = remplissage.range("T63:T70").Value

        pts1.range("K19:K26").Value = remplissage.range("U63:U70").Value

        pts1.range("N19:N26").Value = remplissage.range("V63:V70").Value

        pts1.range("P19:P26").Value = remplissage.range("W63:W70").Value

        pts1.range("S19:S26").Value = remplissage.range("X63:X70").Value

    'output

        pts1.range("C28:C35").Value = remplissage.range("Y63:Y70").Value

        pts1.range("D28:D35").Value = remplissage.range("Z63:Z70").Value

        pts1.range("G28:G35").Value = remplissage.range("AA63:AA70").Value

        pts1.range("I28:I35").Value = remplissage.range("AB63:AB70").Value

        pts1.range("K28:K35").Value = remplissage.range("AC63:AC70").Value

        pts1.range("N28:N35").Value = remplissage.range("AD63:AD70").Value

        pts1.range("P28:P35").Value = remplissage.range("AE63:AE70").Value
        

    Else 'clear "merged" cells
    
        pts1.range("C19:S26") = " "
    
        pts1.range("C28:P35") = " "

    End If
    
p_a = p_a + 27

r_a = r_a + 8

Next t

End Sub
```

worksheet PTS-1 don't use fused cell but worksheet Remplissage do and the only way i found to paste information W/O changing character form is with .value which work with fused cell

code like pts1.range("c19:c26").Value = remplissage.range("Q63:Q70").Value work as intended except that it doesn’t loop trough the worksheet which is required. there is in total 30 sheet where i need to write information.

the 8 line of code tableau_ep(1, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a, 1).Value also work as intended which is to loop trough 30  different cells but i have to create a line of code for every cells. in total there is 120 individual cell so i would need to create 120 line of code. these 8 line replace the code pts1.range("c19:c26").Value = remplissage.range("Q63:Q70")

is there a way to put a range inside both tableau_ep(1, p_a) and tableau_er(r_a, 1)?

Comment: `For i = 1 To 7: tableau_ep(1 + i, p_a).Value = tableau_er(r_a + i, 1).Value: Next i` For loops in VBA are very straightforward. You can read about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement).

Comment: You have looping element `t` which you have set up in your loop, but then you have not included it anywhere in your code. You need to do something like `pts1.range("K19:K26").Offset(t).Value = remplissage.range("U63:U70").Offset(t).Value` which would now cause the range to move down the sheet as `t` increments

Comment: i used `pts1.range("c19:c26").Offset(, t - 1).Value = remplissage.range("q63:q70").Offset(r_a - 1, 0).Value` and it is working, thanks you